# WCF self hosting Service run ConsoleApp.exe dosn´t work but inside vs2012 well

Tags: c#, wcf, self-hosting

i got a noopy problem, if i run my self hosted WCF (WCF service Lib + console app) service inside VS everything works fine.
if i want to run the consoleapplication.exe in the project dir, it looks like everything works fine, but it doesn´t. (i´m new to c#)

I`ve tested:
to run it as admin (firewall off and on)
to reservate my service via http urlacl

Works fine means that i can access my service remotely.
Works not fine means that i not evan can access it through localhost.

Are there any dependencies missing?

Thank you in advance!

App.config of the consoleApp:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="NewBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"
                    policyVersion="Default" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior" name="SampleEmpServiceLib.EmpService">
            <clear />
            <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SampleEmpServiceLib.IEmpService"
                listenUriMode="Explicit" />
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8060/EmpS" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                contract="SampleEmpServiceLib.IEmpService" listenUriMode="Explicit" />
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8888/EmpS" binding="netTcpBinding"
                contract="SampleEmpServiceLib.IEmpService" listenUriMode="Explicit" />
            <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/EmpS" binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
                contract="SampleEmpServiceLib.IEmpService" listenUriMode="Explicit" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/EmpS/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The Code of the Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using SampleEmpServiceLib;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(EmpService));

        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("running on endpoints:");
        foreach (ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint in host.Description.Endpoints)
            Console.WriteLine(serviceEndpoint.Address.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("running");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you simply running the consoleapplication.exe found in **projectdir\bin\debug\consoleapplication.exe**?

Comment: jep i do. I run just the projectdir\bin\debug\consoleapplication.exe

Comment: can we see your ServiceModel section from config

Comment: okay, it looks, base address you should pass to the constructor of ServiceHost. Could you show code how do you start service?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest some updates to config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NewBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"
              policyVersion="Default" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior" name="SampleEmpServiceLib.EmpService">
        <clear />
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SampleEmpServiceLib.IEmpService" listenUriMode="Explicit" />
        <endpoint address="dual" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="SampleEmpServiceLib.IEmpService" listenUriMode="Explicit" />
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" contract="SampleEmpServiceLib.IEmpService" listenUriMode="Explicit" />
        <endpoint binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="SampleEmpServiceLib.IEmpService" listenUriMode="Explicit" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/EMPS" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8888/EMPS" />
            <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: my problem is still there... in which relation stands the app. config of my service lib to the app.config of my console? esp. my endpoints

Comment: if I understood correctly than there are no relation, you have only one app.config for application you are running. It means you should copy servicemodel to console app.config

Comment: ha you are THE GUY!!!! i only had to remove my app.config of my service lib :) thanks a lot!!! since i costumized my consoleapp app.config i got response but without any information of the service. that was the problem... cause the vshost started the service as well as the consol app and so i get my service through the endpoints of my servicelib :P my fault.